# unit test fails when the component is marked as ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, angular-forms

I have the angular component l

```
@Component({
  selector: 'aas-add-option',
  templateUrl: './add-option-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-option-modal.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
```

having form group

```
this.formBuilder.group({
      newOptionInput: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(150),
        Validators.pattern(this.htmlPattern),
      ]),
      newOptionHint: new FormControl(''),
    });
```

==============================
.html file

```
<vt-modal-footer>
    <button
      vtButton
      ot-auto-id="AAResultsAddModalCancelButton"
      [disabled]="isLoading"
      (click)="closeModal()"
    >
      {{ 'Cancel' | translate }}
    </button>
    <button
      vtButton
      color="neutral"
      class="slds-m-right_medium"
      ot-auto-id="AAResultsAddModalSaveAndAddAnotherButton"
      [disabled]="
        !optionsForm?.get('newOptionInput').value?.trim() ||
        !optionsForm?.get('newOptionInput').valid   <--HERE BUTTON DISABLED CHECK
      "
      (click)="onSaveAndAddAnother()"
    >
      {{ 'SaveAndAddAnother' | translate }}
    </button>
    <button
      vtButton
      color="primary"
      *ngIf="!isLoading"
      ot-auto-id="AAResultsAddModalSaveButton"
      [disabled]="
        !optionsForm?.get('newOptionInput').value?.trim() ||   <--HERE BUTTON DISABLED CHECK
        !optionsForm?.get('newOptionInput').valid
      "
      (click)="addOption(true)"
    >
      {{ 'Save' | translate }}
    </button>
  </vt-modal-footer>
```

spec.ts

```
fit('should saveNewOptionButton and saveAndAddAnotherButton should get enabled, when the value is set in input', () => { 
    const saveNewOptionButtonElement = fixture.debugElement.query(
      By.css('button[ot-auto-id="AAResultsAddModalSaveButton"]')
    );
    const saveAndAddAnotherButtonElement = fixture.debugElement.query(
      By.css('button[ot-auto-id="AAResultsAddModalSaveAndAddAnotherButton"]')
    );

    //fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('[ot-auto-id="AAResultsNewOptionInput"]').value = 'ravi'; // basically I want to test, by setting like this.
     
    component.optionsForm.controls.newOptionInput.setValue('ravi'); //trying this too
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.optionsForm.valid).toBeTruthy(); <- got failed 
    expect(saveNewOptionButtonElement.nativeElement.disabled).toBe(false); <- got failed 
    // expect(saveAndAddAnotherButtonElement.nativeElement.disabled).toBe(false); <- got failed 
  });
```

Now I need to unit test the Formcontrol by setting the value to the input DOM and expect the button to be enabled since the value is set in the specs,

But if I remove the `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` from the @Component, things are working fine, but I want the Change Detection Strategy to be on the component.

So the question is why my spec fails when the @Component has
`changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and what I should make the change to make it work in my Spec

Comment: I think this is a known issue. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12313 (Check out sumegha26 answer here) and check this out as well https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/how-to-test-onpush-components-c9b39871fe1e

Answer (score 8):

When working with OnPush components in tests you should be aware that `fixture.detectChanges()` doesn't trigger change detection on undeflying component's view but rather on host view.

In order to remedy this behavior you can get hold of actual component's changeDetector like this:

```
// fixture.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
const cdRef = fixture.componentRef.injector.get(ChangeDetectorRef);
cdRef.detectChanges();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but according to the latest angular, this is fixed. I just upgraded the angular latest version and it started working. thanks for the answer though

Comment: @RONE I have the same failure on Angular 12